# How do I sum total amount of array in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

How would I sum the total of amount that is returned in array by using Ajax?

Is there other way to calculate the sum with amount of .000 behind?

**Example:**

```js
 for (i = 0; i < data.RecordCount; i++) {

 totalBetAmount += parseFloat(data.Records[i].betAmount);
```

**Result:** 0.22130000001

Comment: welcome to the magic world of floating point numbers ... where nothing is precise

Comment: Do you want to remove the decimal points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: @MohitTanwani yes , correct i wish to move the decimal points  but parseFloat seems not working

Comment: Try with ParseInt to get integer output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inaccuracies result from the fact that many numbers do not have an exact representation in *floating point*, which is what JavaScript uses to store numbers.

A pragmatic solution is to round your result to a certain number of decimals after the decimal point, like so:

```
totalBetAmount = Math.round(totalBetAmount*100000000)/100000000;
```

Here is a snippet that shows the original number and the rounded number:

```js
// Sample data
var data = {
    Records: [
        { betAmount: 0.0001 },
        { betAmount: 0.0001 },
        { betAmount: 0.0001 },
    ],
    RecordCount: 3
};    

var totalBetAmount = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.RecordCount; i++) {
   totalBetAmount += parseFloat(data.Records[i].betAmount);
}
console.log('before:', totalBetAmount);
// round of inaccuracies, assuming decimals
totalBetAmount = Math.round(totalBetAmount*100000000)/100000000;
console.log('after:', totalBetAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just round the decimal's:

```
Math.round();
```

Comment: No, This is not true! Can you give us an example how does your code work for this question?

Comment: Had you read the comments to the original question you'd understand what he actually meant =.=

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
//this will be total sum of all numbers
var totalSum = (data.Records || []).reduce(function(total, num){
    return parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(num);
});
//now you can do what you want using ParseInt or toFixed...

//convert to INT
totalSum = parseInt(totalSum);

//leave just 2 numbers after decimal like 1.12
totalSum = totalSum.toFixed(2);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ES6 ([ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)), you can use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function (Great [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl98eZpkp-c) to learn the reduce)

Here is a simple example:

```js
var yourArray = [50, 60, 70, 100, 20]
var sum = yourArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum); //Returns: 300
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Ajax but this might be helpul :

```
var arr = [5.33655,6.6655,9.554];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
  sum += arr[i] 
};
console.log(sum.toFixed(3));
```